# Prevent WYSIWYG from stripping html classes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I am using bootstrap 3 with wysiwyg editor , and Whenever i paste some html code after selecting html source button in editor.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
Some Element
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
Some Element
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<img src="somesource" class="img-resposnsive" />
</div>
```

It strip down all class on client side itself, that is while copy pasting, and pastes the code as :-

```
<div>
Some Element
</div>
<div>
Some Element
</div>
<div >
<img src="somesource" />
</div>
```

How can i prevent it doing so.

This is the WysiWYG editor, i am referencing here :- https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this issue](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/pull/341) is still open and the proprosed solution hasn't been merged into the master but the author **jakcarlton** explains:

> This change allows all classes to be carried over by using a "*" in the classes hash
>
> "classes": { "*":1 }` will allow all classes to be carried over,
> otheriwse only those whitelisted

You could manually merge the changes and build it all from source. Or just wait until the merge is approved!

Comment: I edited file :- bootstrap3-wysiwyg5.js , with "container": 1, "*": 1,   But than it only takes container and doesnot take all.

Comment: It makes sense that that won't work; that's not what you need to change. You need to merge in the changes that jakcarlton committed [(see here)](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/pull/341/files) and then build from that source. It might not be easy if you're not familiar with building a library locally from sources, but it may be your only solution until Xing merges the proposed code changes.